# Is webpack + typescript needed for a node.js server in order to implement Angular SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-universal

I have an existing project, a Node API + Angular project : 
https://framagit.org/mael-jarnole/talebear/tree/master

And I am trying to implement SSR, using the official guide:
https://angular.io/guide/universal

Here is my WiP:
https://framagit.org/mael-jarnole/talebear/tree/ssr-wip

The SSR bundle and regular Angular app seem to build fine, my problem is the express server implementation : 
So far Webpack outputs tons of warning and errors that I do not understand (probably coming from my lack of knowledge of webpack), that seem to be coming from third party js imports (mongoose, helmet etc.)

My questions are:

- Is it necessary to use Webpack and typescript for the Node server ? Porting the code can be quite long, I did it in a very quick way, and it is not very Typescript-like so far. I'd love to stick to my Javascript implementation that works.
- Why are there errors when running `npm run webpack:server` on my SSR branch ?
- If the answer is yes to the first question, what should I modify in order to have a working server Webpack configuration ? Where should I look at ? The configuration from the official guide outputs a huge server.js file

Sorry if my question is too broad ! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I started over from another angular + node boilerplate: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter, and merged my project step by step, re installing every dependencies. and my server now works...

So problem solved but no clue why it did not work on my ssr-wip branch.

Comment: Does your WiP show a fully functioning app with ssr. If so, does Webpack still complain about Mongoose on `npm run webpack:server`?